# How to check enable or disable status from Google Fit

Tags: java, android, google-fit

When user disable Google Fit, I want my app to check status whether Google Fit is enabled or disabled. I have only found code to disable the app.

```
public void disableGoogleFit(){
    if(!mClient.isConnected()){
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Fit wasn't connected");
        return;
    }
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient);

    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if(status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit disabled");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Fit wasn't disabled " + status);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How do I detect when the Intent is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Google's [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_5_connect_to_the_fitness_service) documentation, here is the code sample in the document:

```
if (mClient == null && checkPermissions()) {
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
.addConnectionCallbacks(
new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
// Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
findFitnessDataSources();
}
```

This will check the connection to Google Fit.

Hope this helps!